# gpTask: ERROR 000735 Value is required (Input KML, DataFile)

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, python-script-tool, error-000735

I have a Python script tool running perfectly on the ArcGIS server. Trying to run the tool in a web application (JS API 4.6) with the same input KML-file (published on a publicly available webserver). I get always the error `ERROR 000735 Value is required`.

The input KML is defined as a DataFile by using the URL. In the console log, I can trace the DataFile object - the URL is correct and the object defined. The tool requires a GPDataFile as input.

```
var toolUrl="https://...";
function runTool() {        
    var inputFile = new DataFile({url:"http://.../test.kml",});
    var params = {"inputFile":inputFile};
    var gpTask = new Geoprocessor(toolUrl);
    gpTask.execute(params).then(drawResultData);
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. I can't help but wonder if a `DataFile` is the correct input. Please [Edit] the question to describe what other inputs you have tried.

Comment: If not DataFile, then what? I am having the same problem.